# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'audiomentations'

Tags: python, audio, jupyter-notebook, package, librosa

while installing and importing python packages, this module is showing error while importing. How do I fix this?

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import zipfile
from IPython.display import Audio
from pydub import AudioSegment
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
import os
import pickle
import random
from tqdm import tqdm
import datetime
from audiomentations import *
import multiprocessing
import cv2
# # library used to process the audio files
import librosa
import librosa.display
import sklearn.preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, Softmax, LSTM, Embedding, concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, BatchNormalization,GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50, InceptionV3, VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model,Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard, ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping
from IPython.display import Image
```

I have tried running this piece of code in various textbooks (jupyter notebook, vscode and Google Colab) but this doesn't seem to be working along with librosa module too.

The error I am getting is here below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioBDO.png)

and the other error shown in jupyter notebook are here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhydU.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install these modules before importing them:

```
!pip install pydub
!pip install audiomentations
!pip install tensorflow_addons
```